# What is the ".s" suffix in x86 instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

When I disassemble the `.text` sections of some binaries using `objdump` (with both AT&T and Intel syntaxes), I sometimes see instructions with a `.s` suffix, for example: `cmpb.s %bh,%ch`, `sbbl.s %edi,%edi`, or `adcb.s %bl,%dh`.

Does the `.s` suffix have a valid/useful meaning (perhaps not even as a suffix), or is this an artefact of disassembling some data / padding as if it was a sequence of instructions? Thank you.

Comment: Note that `.s` encoding-override suffixes have been replaced by [`{load}` and `{store}` *prefixes*, and also `{vex3}`, `{disp32}` and others](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html).  e.g. `{load}add %eax, %ecx`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To understand what the `.s` suffix means, you need to understand how x86 instructions are encoded. If we take `adc` as an example, there are four main forms that the operands can take:

1. The source operand is an immediate, and the destination operand is the accumulator register.
2. The source operand is an immediate, and the destination operand is a register or memory location
3. The source operand is a register, and the destination operand is a register or memory location.
4. The source operand is a register or memory location, and the destination operand is a register.

And of course there are variants of these for the different operand sizes: 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, etc.

When one of your operands is a register and the other is a memory location, it is obvious which of forms 3 and 4 the assembler should use, but when both operands are registers, either form is applicable. The `.s` prefix tells the assembler which form to use (or in the case of a disassembly, shows you which form has been used).

Looking at the specific example of `adcb %bl,%dh`, the two ways it can be encoded are as follows:

```
10 de   adcb   %bl,%dh
12 f3   adcb.s %bl,%dh
```

The first byte determines the form of the instruction used, which I'll get back to later. The second byte is what is know as a ModR/M byte and specifies the addressing mode and register operands that are used. The ModR/M byte can be split into three fields: Mod (the most significant 2 bits), REG (the next 3) and R/M (the last 3).

```
de: Mod=11, REG = 011, R/M = 110
f3: Mod=11, REG = 110, R/M = 011
```

The Mod and R/M fields together determine the effective address of the memory location if one of the operands is a memory location, but when that operand is just a register, the Mod field is set to 11, and R/M is the value of the register. The REG field obviously just represents the other register.

So in the `de` byte, the R/M field holds the `dh` register, and the REG fields holds the `bl` register. And in the `f3` byte, the R/M field holds the `bl` register, and the REG fields holds the `dh` register. (8-bit registers are encoded as the numbers 0 to 7 in the order al,cl,dl,bl,ah,ch,dh,bh)

Getting back to the first byte, the `10` tells us to use the form 3 encoding, where the source operand is always a register (i.e. it comes from the REG field), and the destination operand is a memory location or register (i.e. it is determined by the Mod and R/M fields). The `12` tells us to use the form 4 encoding, where the operands are the other way around - the source operand is determined by the Mod and R/M fields and the destination operand comes from the REG field.

So the the position the registers are stored in the ModR/M byte are swapped, and the first byte of the instruction tells us which operand is stored where.

Comment: Great answer, I just wanted to add that the .s suffix is GAS convention. No other assemblers use it (but I don't think any of them actually support choosing an encoding). Here's [another page](http://www.strchr.com/machine_code_redundancy) describing the issue with more examples.

Comment: Interesting reading - thanks for that reference. As for other assemblers supporting multiple encodings, I was convinced I'd encountered similar functionality before in another assembler (or possibly disassembler), I just can't remember where or what the syntax was. Might just have been something I wrote myself though.

Comment: GAS has new syntax for encoding overrides, like a `{load}` prefix for the encoding with a r/m source.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html.

Comment: Related: [x86 XOR opcode differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50336269) is a near duplicate, with an answer that focuses on different aspects.

Answer (score 8):

The `.s` instruction suffix swaps the register operands in the instruction encoding ([reference](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html)).

Comment: Hopefully someday a SO post will reveal what recreational drugs these guys were abusing.

Comment: Thank you for the great reference. I had actually made it to that website, but when looking up the various prefixes. In seeing your link, I realized that I failed to make the connection between that website (about binutils) and how it might help me!