# Why does nasm use 0x89 when it assembles a MOV instruction between registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, instructions

Why does NASM use 0x89 opcode (137) when it assembles a `MOV` instruction between two registers?

Here is an example of code assembled using NASM:

```
55      push ebp
89E5    mov ebp, esp
83EC04  sub esp, byte +0x4
31C0    xor eax, eax
C9      leave
C3      ret
```

I wanted something like this:

```
55      push ebp
8BEC    mov ebp, esp
83EC04  sub esp, byte +0x4
33C0    xor eax, eax
C9      leave
C3      ret
```

The reason I wanted 0x8B was: if you view the binary representation of the `MOV` instruction, it looks like this in NASM:

```
Opcode     Mod   Reg   R/M
10001001   11    100   101 (89 E5)
```

The confusing part in this is that the reg operand is the second.

The NASM syntax is this: `0x89 11 source_reg destination_reg`
and the MOV instruction is `mov destination_reg, source_reg`

Comment: Why not? 8B isn't any better.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `0x89`?

Comment: `0x89` is `mov r/m32,r32`. `mov ebp, esp` fits that format, so why would NASM use some other opcode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two opcodes are the same. That's x86's redundancy. The assembler can choose whatever it likes

> A typical instruction of x86 architecture has **two opcodes**. The first of them has a register as the first operand and a register or a memory location as the second one (that's abbreviated `"reg, reg/mem32"` in the opcode reference or `"Gv, Ev"` in the opcode table). The operands for the second opcode are reversed (that's abbreviated `"reg/mem32, reg"` or `"Ev, Gv"`). This makes sense: the processor must know if it copies to the memory, or from the memory. But when both operands are registers, the encoding becomes redundant:

```
                  ; mod reg r/m
03C3 add eax, ebx ;  11 000 011
01D8 add eax, ebx ;  11 011 000
```

There are much more than just reg/reg style like this. See it [here](http://www.strchr.com/machine_code_redundancy)

Different assemblers emit different opcodes, so this technique can be used to [identify the assembler](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=3866#27977)

Some assemblers allow you to choose the encoding. For example GAS can emit the other encoding if you affix `.s` to the end

```
10 de   adcb   %bl,%dh
12 f3   adcb.s %bl,%dh
```

[What is the ".s" suffix in x86 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16746922/995714)