# NASM Intel 64-bit mode: why does 32-bit constant 0xffffffff cause "warning: signed dword value exceeds bounds"

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, immediate-operand

In NASM (2.14.02), the instruction `add rbx, 0xffffffff` leads to

> warning: signed dword value exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]

I'm aware that arithmetic-logic operations in 64-bit mode only accept constants with 32 bits, but 0xffffffff is still 32 bits wide.

Why does NASM emit a warning, and why does it assume a *signed* constant? Does it sign-extend the 32-bit `-1` to 64-bit `-1` (0xffffffffffffffff) and therefore see an overflow? 0x7fffffff works without a warning.

Can I somehow convince NASM that this is not a signed constant, but an unsigned one?

Comment: Related: [why we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62771323) re: why it can't use an `imm64` to encode the `0x00000000FFFFFFFF` 64-bit value you asked for.  Asm source code uses values, not bit-patterns for the encoding of the immediate.  And [x86-64 assembly (AT&T): movq with 32-bit literal into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71733015), also semi-related: [Max 64bit immediate for mov/movq/movabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64289726)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0x00000000FFFFFFFF can't be encoded as a 32-bit sign-extended immediate, and x86 immediates are always sign-extended when they're narrower than the operand-size.

---

Your theory is somewhat correct, the instruction adds the value specified to the register. There is no way to encode an instruction that adds 0xffffffff to the register, because [the only available encodings](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add) for `add`ing an immediate to a 64-bit register are `add r/m64, sign_extended_imm32` or `add r/m64, sign_extended_imm8`.  Only one special encoding of `mov` (with a register destination) can use a 64-bit immediate.

The obvious encoding (stuffing `0xffffffff` into an `imm32`) would in fact add 0xffffffffffffffff to rbx which is not what you requested and would be the same as `add rbx, -1`

There is no way to encode a value into the 32 bit field that results in 0x00000000ffffffff being added to rbx.  Asm source uses values, not bit-patterns for immediates.

You need to do something like this :-

```
mov rcx, 0xffffffff     ; RCX = 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
add rbx, rcx
```

`mov ecx, 0xffffffff` would also set RCX the same way; NASM will optimize this for you to an efficient 5-byte instruction (with [implicit zero-extension to 64-bit when writing a 32-bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)) instead of needing a 10-byte instruction with a 64-bit immediate; see [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434073/whats-the-difference-between-the-x86-64-att-instructions-movq-and-movabsq) for more about the different forms of MOV in machine code.

Comment: And NASM will helpfully optimize to `mov ecx, 0xffffffff` (5 bytes), instead of `mov rcx, 0xffffffff` (10 bytes since it would have to use the imm64 form, not the 7-byte sign_extended_imm32 form).  For other assemblers like GAS or YASM which don't that for you, you should do it yourself for values that fit in 32-bit-zero-extended but not sign-extended.  (GAS will with `as -Os`)

Comment: I see, the Intel manual says: `ADD r/m64, imm32: Add imm32 sign-extended to 64-bits to r/m64". So it is not a feature or problem of nasm, but of the instruction. Btw.: your second code line should be `add rbx, rcx`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ralf: Yes, exactly, an assembler isn't a compiler, so it's limited by what's encodeable in machine code.  (It won't turn one source instruction into multiple machine instructions.  At least NASM won't; some RISC ISAs have some "pseudo-instructions" for convenience.)  And x86-64 only ever has 64-bit immediates for one special form of `mov`.  Otherwise imm8 or imm32 are sign-extended when you're using 64-bit operand-size.  [Implicit zero-extension when writing a 32-bit register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) is a separate thing, useful when putting constants into regs.

Comment: @jcoder: I edited to change the wording slightly: You were using "the value" to talk about the immediate (which gets sign-extended on decode), but I thought that could be misinterpreted as saying that NASM will sign-extend the value you write in the source code.  (As if it was a 32-bit value, which is of course not what happens.)  And I guess I kind of added my own wording as a TL:DR and some other bits.  If you'd rather I posted some of that as my own answer, let me know.