# x86-64 assembly (AT&T): movq with 32-bit literal into memory

Tags: assembly, x86-64

For an assignment, I have the following code:

```
.global _start

.section .data
arr: .short 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
b: .quad 0x1234567890123456

.section .text
_start:
    movq $arr, b
```

We are to assume that the address of the `arr` label is `0xDEADBEEF`, and decide if the command is legal.

Looking through the Intel manual, I found that `movq` takes a 32-bit number and sign-extends it into the 64-bit memory location (`b` in this case).
When assembling and running the code locally (using `as` and `gdb`), everything seems to work fine, but the address of `arr` is `0x402000`, and not `0xDEADBEEF`. So I tried running:

```
movq $0xDEADBEEF, b
```

but the assembly failed with:

> Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'

which is confusing, as `0xDEADBEEF` is  32-bit literal.
So my two questions are:

1. Why does the above command not work (I assume it has something to do with the sign extension)?
2. **If** the address of `arr` was `0xDEADBEEF`, would the assembler fail as well?

Comment: `0x00000000DEADBEEF` can't be represented as a 32-bit *sign*-extended integer.  2. Yes, you'd get a link error about a failed relocation, similar to what you'd get if you tried to link your `.o` into a shared library or PIE executable (`gcc -pie -nostdlib foo.o`)

Comment: For 2, the assembler itself wouldn't fail, just linking.  The result would be just like if you had some really large arrays that pushed the address outside the low 2GiB.  (Or 4GiB depending on how the compiler used it): [What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168086)

Comment: I knew there was a duplicate somewhere about values that fit in 32-bit zero-extended but not 32-bit sign-extended.  Finally looked carefully at Margaret Bloom's answer on [What's the difference between the x86-64 AT&T instructions movq and movabsq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52434073) and realized that was it!

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now, thank you!
Is there a way to ask the linker to give a specific address to a label? It would be nice to see this behavior in action.

Comment: With a linker script, sure, or `ld -Tdata=0xdeadbeef` to start the `.data` section there, I think.  Or just make some huge objects in `.bss` so the current position gets above 2GiB (but still below 4GiB), like suggested in [What does this GCC error "... relocation truncated to fit..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168086)