# Opcode differences between MOV r/m32, imm32 and MOV r32, imm32

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, opcode, instruction-encoding

These are `MOV` instruction opcodes from the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals*:

`B8+ rd id MOV r32, imm32 OI Valid Valid Move imm32 to r32`.

`C7 /0 id MOV r/m32, imm32 MI Valid Valid Move imm32 to r/m32`.

I disassembled as follows:

```
0:  b8 44 33 22 11          mov    eax, 0x11223344
```

```
0:  67 c7 00 44 33 22 11    mov    DWORD PTR[eax], 0x11223344
```

The questions that I want to ask are:

- Why is the `C7` opcode register/memory (`r/m32, imm32`) instead of memory-only (`m32, imm32`)?
- Is there anytime that we use `C7` for register-only (`r32, imm32`) instead of using `B8` ?

Comment: When the x86 was first designed, it was easier to NOT special-case the c7 opcode and allow the destination to be any r/m not just memory.  So you can make a c7 instruction that writes to a register, but there is no reason to as the b8+ version is shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is opcode `C7` `r/m32, imm32` instead of memory-only `m32,imm32`?

Because it would probably take extra transistors to special-case it and `#UD` fault on the ModRM.mode = 11 (register destination), instead of just running it like other instructions with a write-only destination like `mov r/m32, r32`.

> Is there anytime that we use C7 for `mov r32, imm32` instead of using `B8`?

In 32-bit mode when this design choice was made, no. Except for alignment of later code instead of a separate `nop` -
[What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046814/what-methods-can-be-used-to-efficiently-extend-instruction-length-on-modern-x86)

In 64-bit mode, you'd use C7 with a register destination, but only with a REX.W prefix.  The shortest encoding for `mov rax, -123` is REX.W `mov r/m64, sign_extended_imm32`.  REX.W `B8+rd` is 10-byte `mov r64, imm64`.

Of course, for 64-bit values that fit in 32-bits zero-extended, like `mov rax, 0x0000000012345678`, you should actually use 5-byte `mov eax, 0x12345678`.  NASM will do this for you by default, so will GAS with `as -Os` or `gcc -Wa,-Os`.  Other assemblers won't, so it's up to the programmer to use 32-bit operand-size for non-huge non-negative 64-bit constants.

See examples and more details in

- [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64)
- [What's the difference between the x86-64 AT&T instructions movq and movabsq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434073/whats-the-difference-between-the-x86-64-att-instructions-movq-and-movabsq)

BTW, it's weird to use `[eax]` as the destination in 64-bit mode; 64-bit address size like `[rax]` has more compact machine code, and normally your addresses are properly extended to 64-bit registers even if you were packing them into narrower storage.  That's why your disassembly has an extra `67` byte.

Comment: Man, your answers need a lot of effort :) I stuck on REX.W prefix's and can only see `49` which you mentioned in your answer `REX.W + C7 /0 id` https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding and another question that i don't understand is how exactly 67 hex value represent 67 byte. I know `08` represent 1 byte from that 67 needs to be 12 byte 7 bit ?

Comment: @UPinar: REX.W is a REX prefix with the W bit set, setting the operand-size to 64-bit.  If no other bits in the REX prefix need to be set (when no registers R8-R15 are involved anywhere), the encoding is `48`.