# Does the 'D' field value matter in register-register operation in x86-16?

Tags: encoding, x86, x86-16, machine-code

I was looking how to encode the `mov` instruction when both operands are registers. Looking at the [manual](https://edge.edx.org/c4x/BITSPilani/EEE231/asset/8086_family_Users_Manual_1_.pdf#page=164), the encoding uses the, 1-bit, 'D' field. It changes whether the source or the destination is specified by the 'REG' field. But, as both operands are registers, I can just change the order in the encoding between the 'R/M' field and 'REG' field according to the value of the 'D' field, making:

> `mov ax, ax` = 100010**0**111000000 = 100010**1**111000000
>
> `mov ax, bx` = 100010**0**111**001***000* = 100010**1**111*000***001**

I confirmed the equivalence using an online x86-16 [disassembler](http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?opcodes=8BC1&arch=x86-16&endianness=little&baddr=0x00000000&dis_with_addr=True&dis_with_raw=True&dis_with_ins=True#disassembly). I did not, though, execute both on my computer to test if they are indeed equivalent.

So. Is there any actual difference between the two ways of encoding? Is it just a matter of preference/style? And, if within scope and possible, is there a preferred way?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: @emc, thank you for answering/commenting. Apparently, the x86-16 encoding is very complex and inefficient for the programmer.  But it may be a trade.

Comment: Both directions are supported in order to allow the R/M operand to be either the source or the destination. For two-register operation this causes such a redundancy. A86 is well known for having a specific pattern of encoding choices in redundant cases, which was intended to find unregistered users of that assembler.

Comment: there are 2 ways to encode reg-reg operations: [Encoding ADC EAX, ECX - 2 different ways to encode? (arch x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22217436/995714), [Why does nasm use 0x89 when it assembles a MOV instruction between registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19467610/995714)