# How similar is assembly language to its corresponding machine language?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

It's very common to listen to, or read comments like: "assembler is practically a machine code, but using symbols instead of direct binary codes".

My question is: "how much truth does such kind of affirmation hold in general?"

Comment: It's a human readable representation of machine code with some facilities to make it easier to write.  There is a very close correspondence.

Comment: If you strictly mean the instructions only and furthermore ignore pseudoinstructions, linker fixups and other minor encoding variations it is pretty close, yes :) ARM manual for example is full of stuff like _"In certain circumstances, the assembler can substitute MVN for MOV, or MOV for MVN. Be aware of this when reading disassembly listings."_

Comment: Read the processor manuals, the instruction set is couched in terms you’ll use in assembly language. While it’s not unreasonable to ask a question like this, a very quick examination of instruction sets will give you the answer. Have you done that?

Comment: For most ISAs, there isn't much wiggle room in how to encode an asm source-level instruction.  But for some, like x86-64, there are some choices.  Assemblers pick the shortest, but even within that there's sometimes a choice.  Usually this doesn't affect performance, e.g. [x86 XOR opcode differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50336269).  Some assemblers have syntax to distinguish those variants, like [What is the ".s" suffix in x86 instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16746922)

Comment: Sometimes there is a perf difference, [Which Intel microarchitecture introduced the ADC reg,0 single-uop special case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51664369) doesn't work for the no-modrm `adc al,0` special encoding, only for the 3-byte `adc r/m8, imm8` encoding.  Or [How to force NASM to encode \[1 + rax\*2\] as disp32 + index\*2 instead of disp8 + base + index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48848230)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with a "plain text" representation of machine code (e.g. with opcodes/numbers replaced with mnemonics, addresses/numbers replaced with labels); then most assemblers also:

a) Allow more complicated expressions in operands (e.g. allow something like "`mov eax,(1234*5+6)/7` where the assembler calculates the right value for a "`mov eax,882`" instruction).

b) Have preprocessors allowing you to write macros, etc. Often this includes conditional code, and sometimes it's powerful enough to allow you to create a new language and/or high level language constructs (e.g. imagine "while" and "endwhile" macros).

c) Can auto-select the most optimal encoding. For example, if the instruction could be encoded with a 32-bit immediate operand or an 8-bit immediate operand that is sign extended to 32 bits; then the assembler might look at the operand and determine if the shorter sign extended encoding will work.

All of these things make a huge difference for source code maintenance - e.g. if you add a few instructions somewhere you don't have to manually re-calculate all the addresses/offsets for call/jump/branch targets and data accesses; you can do a "#define COST_OF_CHEESE 123" in one place to make it easy to change later (without having to find everywhere the value was used); etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, using y86.

```
add %rdi, %rsi
```

Becomes something like

```
00 01 02
```

Basically, `00` is the byte representation of the opcode `add`. When the computer sees an `add`, it knows to interpret the next two bytes as registers (this is *slightly* more complex in x86). `01` and `02` are the byte 'names' or encodings for the registers `%rdi` and `%rsi` respectively.

Some parts of this example may not be entirely reflective of reality, but this is basically the correspondence between machine code and assembly. Instructions are opcodes + 1-5 bytes that are interpreted differently depending on the opcode.

Comment: Different ISAs work differently; most modern ISAs use fixed-with instructions, or a mix of 2-byte and 4-byte, with opcode being a bitfield within an instruction.  x86 does (usually) use a whole byte or two as opcode, but the operand encoding is via a single ModRM byte which can signal additional bytes (SIB and/or constant displacement) for memory operands.  x86 only has 8 registers, so two 3-bit fields plus a 2-bit addressing mode fit in one byte.  (x86-64 uses a REX prefix to provide an extra bit to each reg field for 16 regs). It's silly for y86 to use two separate bytes to encode regs.

Comment: @PeterCordes You did not read the part of my answer where I very clearly stated that my example is meant to illuminate the general idea, not be 100% correct. You are also bikeshedding y86, which is nonsensical, as y86 was quite literally created for the purposes of pedagogy.

Comment: The last sentence of your answer, *Instructions are opcodes + 1-5 bytes that are interpreted differently depending on the opcode.*, looked like it was intended to describe the general case of other ISAs, not just your y86 example in particular.  That's why I commented.  Re: y86 being simplistic: yes, but two halves of one byte would be pretty much as simple.  Anyway, point being, real world ISAs don't waste that much coding space, so an example from a teaching ISA isn't representative of how real machine code packs fields together within bytes or words.

Comment: (And BTW, I'm not the downvoter on this answer.  I don't think it deserved one.  I don't think it's general enough that I'd want to upvote it either, but with some improvements to make it clearer that *all* of this is y86-specific, and the general case usually involves bitfields, often in fixed-width instructions, it would be decent.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I understand now. Before, I assumed that you had taken issue with the lax nature of my answer. Now I see that you were just providing real-world details as further elaboration. I sincerely apologize for being so abrasive and thank you for your patience.

Comment: Yup, cheers, glad we got that sorted out. :)